# localhost:3000 won't load while server is running, but it works after I restart the computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, localhost

Basically, when I type in "rails server" in the terminal, the server starts running, but my localhost:3000 page won't load. However, when I restart the computer and do the exact same thing, the page loads normally.

I've had this issue for a while now, but I haven't been able to figure out when exactly and why this happens. Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is in log/development.log?

Comment: Be explicit about everything, the less information we have the less we can help? Copy the logs if needed to a paste bin or the relevant lines in your question. What errors did you get? Did you tried other browsers?

Comment: Hey, can you post the url you are typing in?  Are you typing in localhost:3000, 127.0.0.1:3000, or 0.0.0.0:3000?  Describe the order of how you type these in.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in some other port like say 3001 as:

```
rails server -p 3001
```

If it is working than try it again on 3000 as the command above.
I thing some other software is using your 3000 port that's why its not responding.